# VS 2013 Community Add new Typescript file missing

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, failed-installation

Downloaded and Installed Typescript 1.4 from typescript page into VS 2013 Community Den Update 4.

Following install (no error messages), I tried to add a new typescript file.  I expected to see such an option in the righ-click menu on "ADD new".  Cannot find any reference to typescript files anywhere in any of my projects.

I can manually create a file and give it a ts extension in the "Scripts" directory of my project.  However, there is no intellisense and no indication that a "shadow" js file has been created.

I'm at a loss as to how to get typescript working in VS 2013 Community Edition

Comment: It makes more sense to post on the TypeScript teams github page. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript

Comment: This is a Visual Studio issue/  I can create a new Typescript project and do all the stuff in the typescript demos.  However, when I go into an existing project (created well before typescript was available), I am unable to see any typescript related options in the various "Add New" menus.  It is as though, in my existing projects, VS is unaware that typescript has been installed and can be successfully run in the new typescript (test) project!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem.

To use typescript in conjunction with an existing project in Visual Studio, I had to add a new project (using the typescript template) to the solution containing my existing project.  Then, I could add new typescript files to the typescript project.

The generated javascript files in the TypeScript project could then be made available to the pages in the existing (co-)project by selecting the "Output to Folder" option on the Typescript project, specifying the scripts folder in the other project.